# Changing a state with the route changes in ReactJS and react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, axios

In my `App.js` file I'm importing a `Page.js` component and placing it on the page using `<Page />`. In the page component I'm setting a state relative to that component. I'm then using `react-router` when the user selects a new page.

The state I'm setting is being passed from page to page and I need to reset that of my state when the page changes. I've tried doing `this.setState({archive:[]})` inside `componentDidMount()`, `componentWillMount()`, `componentWillUnmount()`, and `componentDidUpdate()` but they either didn't work or caused errors.

**Update:**

I've updated the code a bit. I set `this.archiveData` in my `constructor`.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        title: 'David Powell',
        nav: {},
        currentPage: "",
        pageContent: "",
        pageTitle: "",
        pageTemplate: "",
        pageId: 0,
        pageCustomMeta: {},
        archiveData: []
    }
}
```

When a page is called I set the values based on what the api returns. I'm resetting the `archivedData` since that is filled based on what gets passed to the `page component` as a prop.

```
getPageData(slug){
    console.log(this.state);
    axios.get('http://admin.sitedata.co/pages?slug='+slug)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);

        this.setState({
            pageContent:response.data[0].content.rendered,
            currentPage:slug,
            pageTitle:response.data[0].title.rendered,
            pageTemplate:response.data[0].template,
            pageId:response.data[0].id,
            pageCustomMeta:response.data[0].post_meta,
            archiveData:[]
        },function(){
            console.log(this.state);
            /*
            *   set the page title
            *   check if the page is at home
            *   get page custom meta
            */
            document.title = this.state.pageTitle;
            this.isHome();
            //this.getPageCustomMeta(this.state.pageId);
        });

    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Everything gets updated correct: the page content changes, the title updates, etc. The `console.log` shows the `archiveData` is empty but it doesn't get updated on the page itself, it still persists.

Comment: more code, please.

Comment: When a component mounts, it shouldn't have a state in the first place unless you added it on purpose before mounting. React-router passes a data component when it routes, it doesn't maintain a passed around state. Definitely need more code.

Comment: There should be a routing object in props of the route target component.

Comment: Question updated with code and more info.

Comment: This is an older post. I'm unsure if you still need help. If so, try recreating this on a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io). This will give anyone wanting to troubleshoot a clear view of what your code does and it'll help with debugging.